# Hyper-V private/internal network providing ipv4 address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ipv6, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu 15 running under Hyper-V. When I use external network then the VM is assigned with an ipv4. When I switch to internal or private network, the VM is assigned with an ipv6 instead. A side effect is that during boot the VM waits for network configuration for about 2 minutes. After a while I see also the message "Waiting for up to 60 more seconds for network configuration". In the end I get the linux login prompt and when I login and do ifconfig I see that I have inet6 address.

What can I do to switch to ipv4?